# Adding a split/broken axis to a ggplot2 code

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to add a broken/split axis to my R code on the x-axis (actually the y-axis because it is flipped). However after many attempts (hours), the codes I apply doesn't work.

Edit- Adding sample data provided by LTyrone:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggbreak)


Sample data df <- data.frame(Name = c("Ellesworth",
>                        "Elmer Thomas",
>                        "Frederick",
>                        "Lawtonka",
>                        "Walters (Dave Boyer)",
>                        "Waurika"),
>                  Result = c(47, 248, 30, 45, 48, 43))
> 
> df$Name <- factor(df$Name)
```

Codes I have tried:

```
scale_y_break(c(60,240), scales="free")

scale_y_break(c(60,240), scales='free',expand = expansion(mult = c(0,.5)))

scale_y_cut(breaks=c(60,240), which=c(1, 3), scales=c(3, 5))
```

My data is large but simple—lake names on the y-axis and chlorophyll levels on the x-axis. The attached picture is the closest I have come to applying a split axis, but this looks odd and does not accomplish what I want.

[image: Broken axis attempt].

my code:

```
PB1_R_Data %>%
ggplot(., aes(x=Name, y = Result)) +

geom_col(aes(x=forcats::fct_rev(reorder(Name,Name)), y=MeanGrowSeason))+ 

(aes(x = Name, y = Result, fill = "Mean Chlorophyll a")) +

scale_fill_manual(name = NULL, values = c("Mean Chlorophyll a" = "#1ca6df")) +

geom_point(mapping=aes(y = `MaxGrowSeason`, pch = 16, color = "black"),  
size = 3, fill = "black", stat = "summary", fun=max)+

geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'solid', color = 'black') +

geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 10, linetype = 'Middle'), color = "#d15420", 
size = 1) +

geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 20, linetype = 'Upper'), color = "#d15420", 
size = 1)+

labs(title = "PB1 (2002-2023)
Chlorophyll a for the Growing Season (May-Sep)",
x = "",
y=expression(plain("Chlorophyll ")~italic("a")~~plain("(mg/l)")), family="mono")+

labs(linetype='')+ 

theme_minimal() +
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=11,family = "Calibri", face="plain"),
legend.text = element_text(size=11,family = "Segoe UI", face="plain"),
axis.title.x = element_text(size=11, family = "Segoe UI", face="plain")) +

theme(text=element_text(size=12,family="Segoe UI"))+

theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0))+
coord_flip() + 
 
scale_color_manual(values = c("#004e9a"),
labels = c("Maximum Chlorophyll a")) +
scale_shape_identity()+
labs(colour = "")+
theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: I get it, I often spring-load to that as well, not always noticing small hints like that. I tend to prefer when the OP is explicit about it, but I think this is (just?) clear enough. Thanks @Peter

Comment: Have updated my answer to deal with your title alignment issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update as per OP's comment***

You haven't provided a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example), but here's a reprex that will help. I haven't looked at the source code for `ggbreak` but it appears the default behaviour for `scale_y_break()` is to align axis titles to one of the 'splits' or to the far left. However, using `hjust =` and `vjust =`, you can customise title placement. You may need to rely on your 'eyechromometer' (e.g. trial and error) to get it how you want it. In this example, I have attempted to align your titles to the `panel.grid`. If you want your titles aligned to the entire plot, use `hjust = 0.5`. Also note the inclusion of `expand = c(0, 0)`, this makes for a nicer looking plot IMO. This setting causes the axis labels either side of the break to overlap so I've adjusted the break space to 0.4 to avoid overlaps. You can remove these additions if they do not suit:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Ellesworth",
                       "Elmer Thomas",
                       "Frederick",
                       "Lawtonka",
                       "Walters (Dave Boyer)",
                       "Waurika"),
                 Result = c(47, 248, 30, 45, 48, 43))

df$Name <- factor(df$Name)

df %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = factor(Name, level = rev(Name)), y = Result)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,250,20), limits = c(0,250)) +
  scale_y_break(c(60,240), space = 0.4, ticklabels = c(seq(0,250,20), 250),
                expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(title = "PB1 (2002-2023)
                Chlorophyll a for the Growing Season (May-Sep)",
       x = "",
       y = expression(plain("Chlorophyll ")~italic("a")~~plain("(mg/l)")),
       family = "mono") +
  labs(linetyp = "") + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        # Adjust to suit
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15,
                                  hjust = 0.6, 
                                  vjust = 0.2),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15,
                                   hjust = 0.6, 
                                   vjust = 0.2))
```

[image: result]

Comment: This works well, thank you @L Tyrone! The x-axis title moves when applied and I'm not sure how to fix that, but overall this is the best (most useful) answer I have received so far :)

Comment: @011235813 - you are welcome. `ggbreak` is great for creating customised split axes but other elements becomes inflexible in the process. I'll have a nosey at your axis title issue when I can and will update my answer if I find a solution.